# How to achieve offline support in ionic 3 using AWS Apollo Angular?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, ionic-framework, aws-appsync

1. How do you know if you're online and offline in Mobile App?
2. How to update(Mutate) data in offline mode.
3. If you come online, how do you refetch all data or keep using cached data?
4. What are the requirements for offline operation? What do you expect to happen with mutations, for example?

I am able to query and fetch data using Apollo-Angular from AWS API.
But I am unable to update and delete data in Offline mode (No internet connectivity )

I am referring following link for same. 
 [Apollo Angular Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html)